# npm express cant find middleware

Tags: node.js, express, npm

I have installed npm express and serve-flavicon, they are present in `npm ls` and `npm ls --global` but I'm still getting `Error: Most middleware (like favicon) is no longer bundled with Express and must be installed separately`

```
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');

const express  = require('express');
const app = express();
const favicon = require('serve-favicon');

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.favicon('public/favicon.ico'));

const options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem')
};

https.createServer(options, app).listen(8000);
```

Comment: `express.favicon()` -> `favicon()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using what you imported.

```
app.use(favicon('public/favicon.ico'));
```

Answer (score -1):

If you using Express 4 o above than use this code instead.
`Using app.use(express.favicon())`
on Express 4 gives: Most middleware (like favicon) is no longer bundled with Express and must be installed separately. Please see github.com/senchalabs/connect#middleware. Alternatively, you can supply no favicon with